# The connect option is disabled for my windows VM in azure

Tags: azure

I have a windows VM created through azure management portal named as SQL1.
private port 3390

the VM is running but it doesnt have the connect option enabled.
what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: I just found out that the private should be 3383 for remote desktop connection. I made that change and it worked for me. :) :)

Comment: Great that you fixed it. Now... either  post your resolution as an answer (not as comment) and mark as answered, or delete your question. Otherwise this question just hangs out here unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying u r answer in the comment

So open private port 3383 and it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the private port should be 3383 for remote desktop connection. I made that change and it worked for me. :) :)